# Can not see my app on App Store from an iPad

Tags: ipad, app-store

I have an application available on the App Store.
I can search and download the app from an iPhone...

From an iPad, when I search for the application...i cannot find the app....

What can be the pb ?

For information:
- the app is not an universal app.
- telephony and gps are required in the plist file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see it from the iPad because it's not available for iPad users; Apple filters the store results to be appropriate on each device.

Answer (score 0):

In fact GPS requirement and telephony were present in my plist file.. and according to the previous post, AppleStore make a filter on the apps regarding targeted device.